# div within a page scroll to a certain point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, scrollbar

I have a situation where I have a vertical un-ordered list which is set to overflow:scroll. This div has the ability to stick to a certain height and scroll through the list items. each list item when clicked displays a new set of information but when clicked appears again on the new page (so it is always visible to click on new subjects). The situation I want to handle is to set the scroll bar of the un-ordered list within the page to a set point on page load so that when a button is clicked the scroll bar of the un-ordered list does not always go back to the top but it remains at the point of the button that the person clicks on.
I have searched around and seen some javascript/Jquery solutions for a page scroll bar, but my situation is specifically for the un-ordered list within the page.
I hope this question is not to complicated and I hope someone can help! :)

Comment: Add sample code or create a jsfiddle for better understanding.

Comment: you will have to track the position of the scroll bar and then look it up on the reload.  You can do this in a cookie, user's profile or any other relevant storage. How do you want this setting to persist?

Comment: I have no experience with cookies, so ill have to do some research, but I want the scroll bar to stay there until the next tab is clicked by the person moving the scroll bar to the next button and then stay until the next tab is clicked so on and so forth.